# How to count threshold number of occurences per group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Sorry for the title :) and I couldnt find proper suitable title for this question.

I have a table where I wanted to count the occurences only upto certain amount of occurences in SQL big query. For example

```
A     B     C
abc   ab    80
abc   ab    80
abc   ab    80
bcd   ah    90
```

Solution expected grouping by A
If I give group by it counts all the occurences of column A (abc)

```
A     B     C    count
abc   ab    80   2     *     
abc   ab    80   1     *
bcd   ah    90   1
```

where * indicates threshold and splitting of row values

I wanted the threshold to have count 2. Hence we can restrict it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try creating a partition on `A`, `B`, `C`, and the row number minus one divided by two:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT A, B, C,
        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B, C ORDER BY A, B, C) - 1) / t2.th AS rn
    FROM yourTable t1
    INNER JOIN threshholds t2
        ON t1.A = t2.A
)

SELECT A, B, C, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM cte
GROUP BY A, B, C, rn
ORDER BY A, B, C, COUNT(*) DESC;
```

This assumes that there is a second table `threshholds` which persists the different threshholds for each group.

Comment: A quick [demo in SQL Server](https://rextester.com/HYQ15453), which however should work just as well for BigQuery.

Comment: How can this be solved when the threshold is different each group. Say for abc it is 2 and may be for bcd it may be 3 and so on

Comment: Check the updated answer.  One possibility is that you maintain a second table containing threshholds.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(grp), COUNT(1) AS count   
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c, DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a, b, c) - 1, 2) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
) t
GROUP BY a, b, c, grp
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - result will be

```
Row a   b   c   count    
1   abc ab  80  1    
2   abc ab  80  2    
3   bcd ah  90  1
```

> How can this be solved when the threshold is different each group. Say for abc it is 2 and may be for bcd it may be 3 and so on

```
#standardSQL
WITH thresholds AS (
  SELECT 'abc' a, 2 threshold UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bcd', 3
)
SELECT a, b, c, COUNT(1) AS count   
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c, 
    DIV(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a, b, c) - 1, threshold) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table` x
  JOIN thresholds y USING(a)
) t
GROUP BY a, b, c, grp
```

Comment: How can this be solved when the threshold is different each group. Say for abc it is 2 and may be for bcd it may be 3 and so on